# How to reread perl database query result

Tags: database, perl

I would like to use the results of a query twice.
How do I reposition the pointer to start reading the results from the beginning a second time?
Example below (just printing to screen for simplicity):

```
if ( $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:database=tng;host=ip", "username", "password" ) ) {
    $strSQL = "select * from table";
    if ( $strQuery = $dbh->prepare($strSQL) ) {
        if ( $strQuery->execute() ) {
            while ( @data = $strQuery->fetchrow_array() ) {
                print $data[0];
            }
            --reposition to top and reread the query result and do something else with the data-- $strQuery->finish;
        }
        else {
            $strMsg = "$strDateTime ERROR -- unable to execute statement: " . $strQuery->errstr . "\n";
            print logFile "$strMsg";
        }
    }
    else {
        $strMsg = "$strDateTime ERROR -- unable to prepare statement: " . $dbh->errstr . "\n";
        print logFile "$strMsg";
    }
    $dbh->disconnect();
}
else {
    print logFile "$strDateTime ERROR -- unable to connect to iptables database ... " . DBI->errstr . " \n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't expect an IO library to load the entire file into memory to read it line by line, so why do you expect it from a database library?

Besides, it's totally unnecessary. It's super easy to load the complete result.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
my $data = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sth);

for my $row (@$data) {
    my ($col1, $col2, ...) = @$row;
    ...
}

for my $row (@$data) {
    my ($col1, $col2, ...) = @$row;
    ...
}
```

You can load the data into a [DBD::Sponge](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD::Sponge) if you need a DBI sth.

Comment: When dealing with huge files the loop approach is generally preferred over slurping the file at once. Same applies to large datasets. So the question is IMHO not unnecessary.

Comment: @dgw, The get the feature the OP wants, DBI would have to slurp the entire result set into memory automatically! You're actually agreeing with me.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to say that you can't do this, but it looks as though you can, you just have to `execute` the statement handle again.  Note that this code uses PostgreSQL since I use that (and don't have an installation of MySQL handy), but it should work for you, too.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
my $dbh=DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=db;host=hosty-host-host","username","password")
  or die DBI->errstr;

my $sth=$dbh->prepare("select generate_series(1,5)") or die $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute or die $dbh->errstr;

while(my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array)
{
  print "$row[0]\n";
}

print "\nSecond verse, same as the first!\n\n";
$sth->execute or die $dbh->errstr;

while(my @row=$sth->fetchrow_array)
{
  print "$row[0]\n";
}

$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5

Second verse, same as the first!

1
2
3
4
5
```

Incidentally, I'd recommend error checking by looking at [`err` and/or `errstr`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.618/DBI.pm#err) rather than using a bunch of if-else statements.

**Edited to add:**  If you don't want to `execute` the statement handle again (and reread information from the database), you're probably stuck with either a) storing the data in a (Perl) data structure or b) writing it to file and then reading it in from file (and using `seek` on the file handle as many times as you'd like).

Comment: but I think the execute is requerying the database, which may have changed.  Also, I forgot to mention that I tried seek @data, 0, 0; and that didn't work.

Comment: Well `@data` is an array, not a file handle, and hence it doesn't make sense to use `seek` on it.  Trying `seek` on `$sth` results in the error `"Not a GLOB reference at..."`.  If you can't or don't want to read the data from the database again, then you'll probably have to either save it in a (Perl) data structure of some kind or write it to file.

Comment: Ew ... so once you read it ... it's gone!  I'm surprised perl is limited in this area ... it has to store it somewhere!  It's a shame to add more code to store in an array when it looks like it already is!

Comment: Well, the `while` loop reads the rows one at a time, so once you're done with a row, it moves on to the next one, yes.

Comment: what about prepare_cached?  I can't seem to find details on what prepare vs execute does exactly ... it looks like prepare actually executes ... if so, prepare_cache would work then I simply execute twice.